# Why am I getting an error calling instance_eval with to_proc and not with Proc.new?

Tags: ruby, closures, proc

I'm doing this and it works:

```
class B
  def value
    "X"
  end
end

class A
  def initialize(context)
    @context = context
  end

  def m
    Proc.new do
      value
    end
  end

  def execute
    @context.instance_eval(&m)
  end
end

A.new(B.new).execute #=> "X"
```

But calling `m.to_proc` is not working...

```
class B
  def value
    "X"
  end
end

class A
  def initialize(context)
    @context = context
  end

  def m
    value
  end

  def execute
    @context.instance_eval(&m.to_proc)
  end
end

A.new(B.new).execute #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `value' for #<A:0x007fae2ab02040 @context=#<B:0x007fae2ab02108>>
```

**I want to know why these two examples are different and how to make it work with `to_proc`**

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, you are calling `m`, which returns the result of calling `value`, which is undefined. (And even *if* if were somehow magically calling `B#value`, then `B#value` returns a `String` and `String`s don't respond to `to_proc`, so you would get a `NoMethodError` there.) In the first snippet, you call `m`, which returns a `Proc`.

It looks like you are trying to pass the method `m` *itself* instead of the result of calling it. In Ruby, methods aren't objects, so you can't just grab them and pass them around (and even if methods were objects, then `m` is still the syntax for calling `m`, not for referencing it). You have to ask Ruby's reflection API for a reflective proxy for the method first, using the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method, which returns a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) object representing the method:

```
@context.instance_eval(&method(:m).to_proc)
```

Note that the call to `to_proc` is completely redundant here, since `&` will call `to_proc` anyway if the argument isn't a `Proc` already. (You may have seen something like `foo.map(&:bar)` before, which will invoke [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc).)

```
@context.instance_eval(&method(:m))
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "&" before `m.to_proc` to convert the proc in a block and still not working.